# How to convert this to proper string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, string-conversion

I receive data from a php file I loaded using `URLRequest` in ActionScript 3.
When I trace `data.toString()` I get the following output.

```
systemResult=Invalid%0D%0A%3C%21%2D%2D%20Hosting24%20Analytics%20Code%20%2D%2D%3E%0D%0A%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fstats%2Ehosting24%2Ecom%2Fcount%2Ephp%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0D%0A%3C%21%2D%2D%20End%20Of%20Analytics%20Code%20%2D%2D%3E%0D%0A
```

I want to convert this to proper string. Is there a way to do that, in AS3.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unescape()` to decode the string.

So `unescape(data.toString())` should give you the output as:

```
systemResult=Invalid

<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>

<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```